# Explain an oddity with coax internet signal loss

Tags: coax

I debated which StackExchange site was best to post this question to. Please feel free to move it if I chose wrong.

In my house, coax enters the wall in one bedroom and is terminated 1 foot later at a female connector. Since my computer and cable modem are in another room, at that termination I placed a male-male joiner to which I connected a 25 ft cable. This cable goes through the floor and under the house, where it meets up with **another** male-male joiner, and then another 25 ft cable, which climbs back up through the floor in my computer room, and connects to my cable modem. The reasons for this long rat's nest of a route are historical and forgotten, but most likely due to laziness and simplicity. :-)

Now, once a month or so my internet connection drops out. Most of the time, simply cycling the power on the modem is enough to fix it. Rarely though, when cycling the power does not work, I've observed that disconnecting and then reconnecting the coax cable from the modem (while leaving it powered on) **does** work, which is very strange. But it gets even stranger! Even more rarely, say maybe once every two years, there will be an outage that is not fixed by either of the procedures above. However, in this case if I move back to the first bedroom where the coax enters the house and disconnect/reconnect the connection at the joiner there, then the problem is fixed.

To summarize:

- Most connection dropouts are fixed by cycling modem power
- Maybe 10% require cycling the coax connection at the modem
- Maybe 1% (ultra rare) require cycling the coax connection further upstream from the modem

In none of these "connection cycling" cases are the connections loose or in any other obvious physical way suspect. Can anybody explain this weirdness?

Comment: Consider another possibility -- dropouts external to the house, which are getting resolved in parallel with your own escalating efforts.

Comment: @BenVoigt I have considered that, but the timing is too perfect. For example, this most recent dropout started happening ~36 hours ago. I spent a few minutes toying with the connection at the modem briefly every 12 hours when I was home, and giving up each time. Only at the 36 hour did I go cycle the upstream connection (immediately **after** the downstream cycling failed to work), and the upstream cycle worked within seconds. I've seen this happen multiple times over the past 6 years, each time something similar (a 24+ hour problem is fixed within seconds by cycling the upstream joiner).

Comment: Perhaps the mechanical connections are oxidizing, creating capacitance or degraded electrical contact? Reassembling all with a light coat of mineral oil should eliminate that possibility.

Comment: @rdtsc sounds like that might very likely be the cause, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How hard is it to replace the cable from the first splice point all the way to the modem?

I'd start by replacing that cable, then cutting off and re-terminating the connector on the cable that enters the house.  Also replace any couplers that you are using.

Part of the problem is that the center conductor of the coax cable is untreated copper.  It oxidises over time.  Same with the tin-plated conductors inside the couplers.

Where I live, the cable company will send a competent tech to do all of those things - the customer doesn't have to figure this out themselves.  Even better - they check the actual signal levels entering the premises.  They will replace the cable that enters the premises if it even looks bad.

I've also seen them spend a couple of hours tracking down a bad splice a block away - and fixing it.

Comment: This question is more out of academic curiosity than trying to figure out how I can make the problem go away permanently. It happens rarely enough at this point that it's an annoyance, at some point the annoyance will become large enough to outweigh my laziness, and I'll make it go away forever. But for now I'm just curious how disconnecting and reconnecting a circuit at point A could fix it when doing the same thing to the same circuit at point B doesn't. It doesn't really make much sense, which is why it is curious. :-)

Comment: I think the couplers oxidizing sounds like a pretty probable cause, thanks!